# Parsing strings to dataframe with two for loops

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a code that i am trying to implement using two lists. The gist of the code is as below;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
LX = ['A','B','C','D']
DX =['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6']
my_dfs = {}
for name in LX:
    my_dfs[name] = pd.read_csv(r"C:\HSTS\OB\ODO\%s.csv" % name, delimiter=';')
    cols = [0,19,20,21,22,23,24]
    my_dfs[name]=my_dfs[name][my_dfs[name].columns[cols]]
    my_dfs[name].columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6']
    for dx in DX:
        my_dfs[name]['dx'] = my_dfs[name]['dx'].diff().abs()
```

The first for loop works with no issues and the string in the LX list is parsed to the dataframe. The second for loop is the issue and i cannot parse the string into the data frame. The goal would to have example;

```
my_dfs[name]['col1'] = my_dfs[name]['col1'].diff().abs()
my_dfs[name]['col2'] = my_dfs[name]['col2'].diff().abs()
```

Comment: `my_dfs[name][dx] = my_dfs[name][dx].diff().abs()` instead of `my_dfs[name]['dx'] = my_dfs[name]['dx'].diff().abs()` ?

Comment: could have sworn i had tried that. But seems to work.Can you ansswer so i can upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is that your second loop is passing a literal string `'dx'` each time, rather than the variable `dx`:

Change

```
...
    for dx in DX:
        my_dfs[name]['dx'] = my_dfs[name]['dx'].diff().abs()
```

to

```
...
    for dx in DX:
        my_dfs[name][dx] = my_dfs[name][dx].diff().abs()
```